# How to trigger update child records on parent update in the same table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers, sql-update

I have a user table that has both child and parent user accounts in it.
Child accounts are indicated by a parent id field

I have created a stored procedure that takes all the necessary info and can update the user's fields successfully when manually run and given a specific ID to update

Then I have a trigger that can successfully get the child users it needs to update.
The problem, however, is when I try and make the trigger call the procedure I get the error

"Can't update table 'userinfos' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger"

Below is my code in which I check before running the stored procedure that the update it triggered on was done on a parent and not a child. This means if it triggered on a child update then it won't run the stored procedure and therefore can't ever get stuck in a loop. (Note both BEFORE and AFTER don't work)

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_child_users` BEFORE UPDATE ON `abcd_virtuemart_userinfos`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        IF OLD.`primary_user_id` = NEW.`primary_user_id` AND (NEW.`primary_user_id` = 0 OR NEW.`primary_user_id` = '' OR NEW.`primary_user_id` IS NULL)
    THEN        
        CALL sys.`update_child_user`(NEW.`company`, NEW.`last_name`, NEW.`first_name`, NEW.`middle_name`, NEW.`phone_1`, NEW.`phone_2`, NEW.`fax`, NEW.`address_1`, NEW.`address_2`, NEW.`city`, NEW.`virtuemart_state_id`, NEW.`virtuemart_country_id`, NEW.`zip`, NEW.`billing_email_address`, NEW.`virtuemart_user_id`);
    END IF;
END
```

And the stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE DEFINER=`~DEFINER HERE~` 
PROCEDURE `update_child_user`(IN `n_company` VARCHAR(64), IN `n_last_name` VARCHAR(48), IN `n_first_name` VARCHAR(48), IN `n_middle_name` VARCHAR(48), IN `n_phone_1` VARCHAR(32), IN `n_phone_2` VARCHAR(32), IN `n_fax` VARCHAR(32), IN `n_address_1` VARCHAR(64), IN `n_address_2` VARCHAR(64), IN `n_city` VARCHAR(64), IN `n_virtuemart_state_id` SMALLINT(1), IN `n_virtuemart_country_id` VARCHAR(255), IN `n_zip` VARCHAR(32), IN `n_billing_email_address` VARCHAR(255), IN `n_virtuemart_user_id` INT(1))
MODIFIES SQL DATA
    UPDATE `userinfos`
    SET    `company` = `n_company` , 
           `last_name` = `n_last_name` , 
           `first_name` = `n_first_name` , 
           `middle_name` = `n_middle_name` , 
           `phone_1` = `n_phone_1` , 
           `phone_2` = `n_phone_2` , 
           `fax` = `n_fax` , 
           `address_1` = `n_address_1` , 
           `address_2` = `n_address_2` , 
           `city` = `n_city` , 
           `virtuemart_state_id` = `n_virtuemart_state_id` , 
           `virtuemart_country_id` = `n_virtuemart_country_id` , 
           `zip` = `n_zip` , 
           `billing_email_address` = `n_billing_email_address` 
    WHERE  `primary_user_id` = `n_virtuemart_user_id`
$$ delimiter ;
```

So how can I go about either just letting this trigger be able to run recursively as there are others I don't or can I change my syntax in some way that doesn't set off the recursive blocking trigger?

Comment: The error already told you the answer, "you can't"; MySQL does not allow triggers to modify the contents of any table involved in the query that activated the trigger(which means never the table the trigger is on).

Comment: @Uueerdo just cause there is an error doing it this way doesn't mean there isn't a different way to to do it

Comment: What I am saying is MySQL does not allow **triggers** to do what you want, and that is what the error is telling you; there are certainly other ways, but none are automatic like triggers.